# This following inequality is hold?$\frac{a^3+b^3}{2ab}\ge\log{\left(\frac{e^a+e^b}{2}\right)}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a.b>0$ following is hold?
>   $$\dfrac{a^3+b^3}{2ab}\ge\log{\left(\dfrac{e^a+e^b}{2}\right)}$$

I see By AM-GM
$$\dfrac{a^3+b^3}{2ab}\ge \sqrt{ab}$$
otherwise
$$\log{\left(\dfrac{e^a+e^b}{2}\right)}\ge\log{e^{\frac{a+b}{2}}}=\dfrac{a+b}{2}\ge\sqrt{ab}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong! Try $a=15$ and $b=11$.